Unable to export Torch model as onnx file (Exception: Model.forward() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given)
I'm trying to export a Torch model as an onnx file, but simply can't make it happen. Here is my code for the export:
z = torch.randn(1, 3, 256, 256, requires_grad=True)

Model = MainModel(net_G=net_G)
torch.onnx.export(Model, z, "PATH/TO/res18-unet.onnx")

The Python interpreter comes back with the following:
TypeError: MainModel.forward() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Here is part of the code for MainModel:
class MainModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, net_G, lr_G=2e-4, lr_D=2e-4,
                 beta1=0.5, beta2=0.999, lambda_L1=100.):
        super().__init__()

        self.device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        self.lambda_L1 = lambda_L1
        self.net_G = net_G.to(self.device)
        # Truncated

    def forward(self):
        self.fake_color = self.net_G(self.L)

    # There are several other functions in this class

I'm not sure how to correct the exception.

Okay, I finally solved this. I needed to save the initial neural network that was built or imported before it was exposed to any training or modification (in my case, I imported it, which was ResNet18). When exporting the bare network in onnx format, the onnx exporter automatically incorporates the trained parameter weights (that is, the pt file that resulted from training) inside the onnx file being created. That took me hours to figure out!
